# VBA matching combobox values with ranges

Tags: vba, combobox

I am trying to match the value in a combobox with values from a range and put matching values into an array.  However, according to the watch window my array is not storing any values.  I think there is something wrong with my reference to the combobox value but I am not sure how to correct it.  Any input appreciated.

ILsearch is the name of my userform

AnSelect is the name of my combobox

```
Dim ia As Long
Dim Anion As Range, AnFind As Range
Dim AnResults() As Variant

    If ILsearch.ICheck1.Value = True Then
    Set Anion = Worksheets("Properties").Range("T7:T600")
    For Each AnFind In Anion
        If AnFind.Value = ILsearch.AnSelect.Value Then
            ia = ia + 1
            ReDim Preserve AnResults(ia)
            AnResults(ia - 1) = AnFind.Row
        End If
    Next AnFind
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Dim ia As Long
Dim Anion As Range, AnFind As Range
Dim AnResults() As Variant

    ia = 0
    If ILsearch.ICheck1.Value = True Then
      Set Anion = Worksheets("Properties").Range("T7:T600")
      For Each AnFind In Anion.Cells
        If AnFind.Value = ILSearch.AnSelect.Value Then
            ia = ia + 1
            ReDim Preserve AnResults(1 To ia)
            AnResults(ia) = AnFind.Row
        End If
      Next AnFind

      MsgBox Join(AnResults, ",")
    End If
```